# "マウスストーカー"の効果を失わずに、セレクトのoptionにもanimationDURATIONスタイルを設定する方法

Tags: javascript, html, css

下記のソースコードは、 文字マウスストーカーにanimationDURATIONスタイルを設定したのですが、
これを設定したらマウスストーカーの効果が失われてしまいました(*初期状態のみ正常に機能します)。
どのように設定しなおせば、マウスストーカーの効果を失わずに、animationDURATIONスタイルを
セレクトのoptionにも設定できるでしょうか。ご教示ください。

＊"文字マウスストーカー"とは、マウスポインタの動きに応じて文字列が付いて回る，技法です。

(ソースコード)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">

<title>animationDURATIONスタイルについて</title>


<style type="text/css">

#myText {
           font-style: italic;
           font-weight: bold;
           font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
           position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;
         -webkit-animation:myText 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
         -moz-animation:myText 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
          animation:myText 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
} 
@-webkit-keyframes myText{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:gold;}
}
@-moz-keyframes myText{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:gold;}
} 
@keyframes myText{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:gold;}
} 

.mog1 {
           font-style: italic;
           font-weight: bold;
           font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
           position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;
         -webkit-animation:mog1 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
         -moz-animation:mog1 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
          animation:mog1 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
} 
@-webkit-keyframes mog1{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:blue;}
}
@-moz-keyframes mog1{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:blue;}
} 
@keyframes mog1{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:blue;}
} 
.mog2 {
           font-style: italic;
           font-weight: bold;
           font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
           position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;
         -webkit-animation:mog2 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
         -moz-animation:mog2 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
          animation:mog2 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
} 
@-webkit-keyframes mog2{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:red;}
}
@-moz-keyframes mog2{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:red;}
} 
@keyframes mog2{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:red;}
} 

.mog3 {
           font-style: italic;
           font-weight: bold;
           font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
           position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;
         -webkit-animation:mog3 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
         -moz-animation:mog3 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
          animation:mog3 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
} 
@-webkit-keyframes mog3{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:olive;}
}
@-moz-keyframes mog3{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:olive;}
} 
@keyframes mog3{ 
      0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1; color:olive;}
} 

 #myText div {position: relative;}
 #myText div div {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;text-align: center;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var txt1="<div class='mog1'>１</div><div class='mog1'>２</div><div class='mog1'>３</div><div class='mog1'>４</div>";
var txt2="<div class='mog2'>５</div><div class='mog2'>６</div><div class='mog2'>７</div><div class='mog2'>８</div>";
var txt3="<div class='mog3'>Ａ</div><div class='mog3'>Ｂ</div><div class='mog3'>Ｃ</div><div class='mog3'>Ｄ</div>";

function anime1(){
document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = txt1;
　　}
function anime2(){
document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = txt2;
　　}
function anime3(){
document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = txt3;
　　}

function output(e){
 var selectedIndex = e.selectedIndex;
 document.getElementById("mess").style.background=e[selectedIndex ].style.backgroundColor;
}


;(function(){
var msg = "ＡＢＣＤ"; 
var size = 26;
var circleY = 0.75; var circleX = 2;
var letter_spacing = 5;
var diameter = 10;
var rotation = 0.4;
var speed = 0.3;

if (!window.addEventListener && !window.attachEvent || !document.createElement) return;
msg = msg.split('');
var n = msg.length - 1, a = Math.round(size * diameter * 0.208333), currStep = 20,
ymouse = a * circleY + 20, xmouse = a * circleX + 20, y = [], x = [], Y = [], X = [],
o = document.createElement('div'), oi = document.createElement('div'),
b = document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat"? document.documentElement : document.body,

mouse = function(e){
 e = e || window.event;
 ymouse = !isNaN(e.pageY)? e.pageY : e.clientY;
 xmouse = !isNaN(e.pageX)? e.pageX : e.clientX;
},

makecircle = function(){
 if(init.nopy){
  o.style.top = (b || document.body).scrollTop + 'px';
  o.style.left = (b || document.body).scrollLeft + 'px';
 };
 currStep -= rotation;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){
  d = document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).style;
  d.top = Math.round(y[i] + a * Math.sin((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleY - 15) + 'px';
  d.left = Math.round(x[i] + a * Math.cos((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleX) + 'px';
 };
},

drag = function(){
 y[0] = Y[0] += (ymouse - Y[0]) * speed;
 x[0] = X[0] += (xmouse - 20 - X[0]) * speed;
 for (var i = n; i > 0; --i){
  y[i] = Y[i] += (y[i-1] - Y[i]) * speed;
  x[i] = X[i] += (x[i-1] - X[i]) * speed;
 };
 makecircle();
},

init = function(){ 
 if(!isNaN(window.pageYOffset)){
  ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
  xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 } else init.nopy = true;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){
  d = document.createElement('div'); d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
  d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
  d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
  oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
 };
 o.appendChild(oi); document.body.appendChild(o);
 setInterval(drag, 25);
},

ascroll = function(){
 ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
 xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 window.removeEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
};

o.id = 'myText'; o.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

if (window.addEventListener){
 window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
 document.addEventListener('mouseover', mouse, false);
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse, false);
  if (/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor))
   window.addEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent){
 window.attachEvent('onload', init);
 document.attachEvent('onmousemove', mouse);
};
})();
// -->
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="black">
<form style="text-align:center;">
　<select id="mess" style="background-color:olive; color:black; font-weight:bold;" onchange="output(this)">
　　<option id="op1" style="background-color:blue;" value="１２３４" onclick="anime1()">１２３４</option>
　　<option id="op2" style="background-color:red;" value="５６７８" onclick="anime2()">５６７８</option>
　　<option id="op3" style="background-color:olive; font-weight:bold" value="ＡＢＣＤ" onclick="anime3(this)" selected>ＡＢＣＤ</option>
　</select> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 次の2点を考慮して質問を修正されることをおすすめします。(1)現象の再現に不必要なスタイルやスクリプトは削除してください（font-styleなどの指定は今回の現象に本当に関係ありますか？）。コードが長過ぎると回答を得にくくなります。(2)インデントに全角スペースを使用しないでください。エラーの原因になります。

Comment: 現象を再現したjsfiddle（https://jsfiddle.net/）を作成し、提示するのがベターです。もしくは編集画面のスニペット機能（http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers）を利用してください。

Comment: かなり削ったつもりでいましたが、これから気をつけます。

初期状態のmsgの１文字ずつにstyleを打てるようにならないか考えていますが、ソースコードを大改造しないといけない感じがします。
"createElement"が鍵を握っているようですが…？

Comment: `option`要素に単純に`animation-duration`のスタイルを指定してみましたが動いているように見えます（https://jsfiddle.net/2bot6tp4/）。

Comment: 意味がよく飲み込めないのですが…個々のoptionにidかclassを設定しないと、animation-durationのスタイルは設定できないと思うのですが。

Comment: 子孫セレクタ（`#mess option`部分）を使用して指定しています。子孫セレクタは質問欄のソース（`#myText div`等）でも利用されています。jsfiddleの検証はご覧になっていただけましたか？

Comment: この"文字マウスストーカー"は、オプションを付けると、function機能に
{
    var t = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value;
    for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).innerHTML = t.charAt(i);
    }
}

を追加して文字数を調節しないと、文字列は現れますが、マウスストーカーの効果が失われてしまいます。しかし、これだと個々のオプション(文字列)にidとかclassは設定できないので、ソースコードのようにしたのです。
jsfiddleの検証は拝見しましたが、"１２３４”と"５６７８"のボタンは機能していませんが…？

Comment: それは質問欄に明記してください。あなたが「"１２３４”と"５６７８"のボタン」で何がしたいのかは私にはわかりませんし、質問欄に記述もありません。上記jsfiddleの検証は「“マウスストーカー”の効果を失」っておらず、「セレクトのoptionにもanimationDURATIONスタイル」が設定されており、現状の本スレッドの問題を解決しているものと考えております。